# Selecting only certain columns during nested relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

If I have a query: `MyModal::with('relation1.relation2')->get()`, how can I limit the fields selected from `relation1`?

`MyModal::with('relation1:column1,column2')->with('relation1.relation2')->get()` selects all fields on `relation1`.

`MyModal::with('relation1:column1,column2.relation2')->get()` gives an SQL error because it tries to find a column named `column2.relation2`.

I'm not sure what other approach there could be, so is this possible, or will fetching nested relations always fetch all fields on the first relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do column select after relation select:
`MyModal::with(['relation1.relation2', 'relation1:column1,column2'])->get()`

Or you can define it in model itself

```
public function relation1()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Relation1::class)->select(['column1', 'column2']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model::query()
->with(array('relation1' => function($query) {
    $query->select('column1', 'column2');
},'relation2' => function($query) {
    $query->select('column1', 'column2');
}))
->get();
```